# Failed building wheel for cython

Tags: python, cython, python-wheel

My OS is Windows11, and i have installed Visual Studio 2015 & 2019.
When i try to use the command "pip install cython==0.27.3"(environment requirements), i got the error below.

```
Collecting cython==0.27.3
  Using cached Cython-0.27.3.tar.gz (1.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: cython
  Building wheel for cython (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [331 lines of output]
      Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37
      copying cython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython
      copying Cython\CodeWriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython
      copying Cython\Coverage.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython
      copying Cython\Debugging.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython
      copying Cython\Shadow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython
      copying Cython\StringIOTree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython
      copying Cython\TestUtils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython
      copying Cython\Utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython    
      copying Cython\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython 
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\BuildExecutable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\Cythonize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\Dependencies.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\Distutils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\Inline.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\IpythonMagic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\AnalysedTreeTransforms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Annotate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\AutoDocTransforms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Buffer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Builtin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\CmdLine.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Code.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\CodeGeneration.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\CythonScope.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\DebugFlags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\ExprNodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\FusedNode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Future.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Interpreter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Lexicon.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Main.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\MemoryView.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\ModuleNode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Naming.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Nodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Optimize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Options.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\ParseTreeTransforms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Parsing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Pipeline.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\PyrexTypes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Pythran.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Scanning.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\StringEncoding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Symtab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\TreeFragment.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\TreePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\TypeInference.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\TypeSlots.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\UtilityCode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\UtilNodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Visitor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Runtime
      copying Cython\Runtime\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Runtime
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Distutils
      copying Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Distutils
      copying Cython\Distutils\extension.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Distutils
      copying Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Distutils
      copying Cython\Distutils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Distutils
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\Cygdb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\DebugWriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\libcython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\libpython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Debugger
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Debugger\Tests       
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\TestLibCython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\test_libcython_in_gdb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\test_libpython_in_gdb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Actions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\DFA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Lexicons.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Machines.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Regexps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Scanners.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Timing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Traditional.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Transitions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Plex
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\TestCodeWriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\TestJediTyper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\TestStringIOTree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\xmlrunner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Build\Tests
      copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestInline.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Build\Tests
      copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestIpythonMagic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Build\Tests
      copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestStripLiterals.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Build\Tests
      copying Cython\Build\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Build\Tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler\Tests       
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestBuffer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestCmdLine.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestFlowControl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestGrammar.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestMemView.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestParseTreeTransforms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestSignatureMatching.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTreeFragment.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTreePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTypes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestUtilityLoad.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestVisitor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Tempita
      copying Cython\Tempita\compat3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Tempita
      copying Cython\Tempita\_looper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Tempita
      copying Cython\Tempita\_tempita.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Tempita
      copying Cython\Tempita\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Tempita
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\pyximport
      copying pyximport\pyxbuild.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\pyximport
      copying pyximport\pyximport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\pyximport
      copying pyximport\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\pyximport
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes
      copying Cython\Includes\openmp.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\cpython     
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\array.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bool.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\buffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bytes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\cobject.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\complex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\datetime.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\dict.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\exc.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc        
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\errno.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\locale.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\math.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\setjmp.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\signal.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stddef.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdint.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\time.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libc
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp      
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\algorithm.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\cast.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\complex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\deque.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\functional.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\map.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\memory.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\pair.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\queue.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\stack.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\typeindex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\typeinfo.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\unordered_map.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\unordered_set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\utility.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\vector.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\numpy       
      copying Cython\Includes\numpy\math.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\numpy
      copying Cython\Includes\numpy\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\numpy
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix       
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\dlfcn.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\fcntl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\ioctl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\mman.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\resource.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\select.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\signal.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\stat.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\strings.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\time.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\types.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\unistd.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\wait.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Compiler\Code.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\ParseTreeTransforms.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Parsing.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Scanning.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Visitor.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Runtime\refnanny.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Runtime
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\codefile -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\cfuncs.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Plex\Actions.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Scanners.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Utility\CConvert.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CpdefEnums.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CppConvert.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\MemoryView.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TestCythonScope.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TestCyUtilityLoader.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\AsyncGen.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Buffer.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Builtins.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Capsule.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CMath.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CommonStructures.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Complex.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Coroutine.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CythonFunction.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Embed.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Exceptions.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ExtensionTypes.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\FunctionArguments.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ImportExport.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\MemoryView_C.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ModuleSetupCode.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ObjectHandling.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Optimize.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Overflow.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Printing.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Profile.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\StringTools.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TestUtilityLoader.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TypeConversion.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\arrayarray.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CppSupport.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cython\Utility
      running build_ext
      building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\Users
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\Users\WideLab      
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\Users\WideLab\AppData
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\Users\WideLab\AppData\Local
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\Users\WideLab\AppData\Local\Temp
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\Users\WideLab\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_tsg9x75
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\Users\WideLab\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_tsg9x75\cython_a7f48f0505cb451f9768c35b7e2705d2
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\Users\WideLab\AppDa
ta\Local\Temp\pip-install-_tsg9x75\cython_a7f48f0505cb451f9768c35b7e2705d2\Cython
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\Users\WideLab\AppDa
ta\Local\Temp\pip-install-_tsg9x75\cython_a7f48f0505cb451f9768c35b7e2705d2\Cython\Plex
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\To
ols\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEB
UG /MD -IC:\Users\WideLab\miniconda3\envs\alphapose\include -IC:\Users\Wid
eLab\miniconda3\envs\alphapose\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
 Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include" "-
IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MS
VC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.
6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.190
41.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\
shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um"
 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-I
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /TcC
:\Users\WideLab\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_tsg9x75\cython_a7f48f0505c
b451f9768c35b7e2705d2\Cython\Plex\Scanners.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpyth
on-37\Release\Users\WideLab\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_tsg9x75\cython_a7f48f0505cb451f9768c35b7e2705d2\Cython\Plex\Scanners.obj
      Scanners.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\To
ols\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LT
CG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\WideLab\min
iconda3\envs\alphapose\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\WideLab\miniconda3\envs\alph
apose /LIBPATH:C:\Users\WideLab\miniconda3\envs\alphapose\PCbuild\amd64 "/
LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\T
ools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Mic
rosoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64" "/L
IBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LI
BPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64" "/
LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64" /E
XPORT:PyInit_Scanners build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\Users\WideLa
b\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_tsg9x75\cython_a7f48f0505cb451f9768c35b7
e2705d2\Cython\Plex\Scanners.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Cytho
n\Plex\Scanners.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37
\Release\Users\WideLab\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_tsg9x75\cython_a7f48f0505cb451f9768c35b7e2705d2\Cython\Plex\Scanners.cp37-win_amd64.lib      
      LINK : fatal error LNK1104: 無法開啟檔案 'build\temp.win-amd64-cpyth
on-37\Release\Users\WideLab\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_tsg9x75\cython_a7f48f0505cb451f9768c35b7e2705d2\Cython\Plex\Scanners.cp37-win_amd64.exp'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\20
19\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1104
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cython
  Running setup.py clean for cython
Failed to build cython
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cython, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm not sure if this is a version issue with Visual Studio or another installation package issue, can someone help me to fix it? Thanks.

My system environment is:
Windows 11
Python 3.7
CUDA 11.3
Pytorch 1.12.1
torchvision 0.13.1

Comment: Could be related: [bug #5028 fatal error LNK1104](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/5028)

Comment: Discussion of another [bug #3941](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3941#issuecomment-742682971) mentions `--install-option="--no-cython-compile"`. Wondering, if it can help.

Comment: I have tried it, but it shows "no such option: --install-option" because my pip version is 23.3.1. 
--install-option was deprecated in pip v22.3 and has been removed completely in v23.1.